# Whitespace error when calling command through variable

Tags: bash, macos

To set the scene, I'm editing my /.bash_profile, and wanted the current directory along with files in said directory within my PS1. While it works, I'm getting a strange error with the spacing:

```
(~) (      12)
```

I don't understand why this is, as — to my knowledge — the code shouldn't be adding that whitespace.

```
lines=$(ls | wc -l)
PS1='\n\e[2m(\w) ($lines)\e[22m\n> '
```

I have no idea as to why this is happening, and someone with some Bash wizardry would be handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PS1` is a little bit different than most variables, at least in how it is used. Its value isn't simply printed to standard error to display the prompt, as is obvious if you compare your prompt to the output of `echo "$PS1"`.

The evaluation rules aren't identical to normal evaluation rules, as you can see here that the leading whitespace in the value of `$lines` isn't removed from the unquoted expansion of `$lines` when the prompt is finally displayed.

One way to work around this is to replace the plain parameter expansion with a shell command that *does* undergo normal evaluation, then capture the output of that command for use in the prompt:

```
PS1='\n\e[2m(\w) ($(echo $lines))\e[22m\n> '
```

Better yet, don't parse the output of `ls`: create an array and output its length:

```
PS1='\n\e[2m(\w) ($(f=(*); echo ${#f[@]}))\e[22m\n> '
```

(Also, unless you are resetting the value of `lines` prior to each prompt, say in `PROMPT_COMMAND`, you are always going to show the file count of the directory you were in when `lines` was set, probably your home directory. Getting the file count *in* the prompt itself gets you the file count of the current directory, whatever that might be.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. While your second, and I assume first, example of code worked, I chose to forego the variable, and just print "ls | wc -l | xargs" to maintain readability, due to my goal of learning.

Comment: Really, don't use `ls | wc -l`. It overcounts if any of the filenames contain newlines themselves. If your goal is to learn, learn to do things the right way, even if the wrong way only hurts you very rarely.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I wasn't aware of that problem.